pyinstallerでexe化したファイルが途中で止まってしまいます。
pythonでダウンロード・ピクチャ・ドキュメント・ビデオ・ミュージックフォルダの中身をゴミ箱に移動する物を作成しました。
python環境のないPCでも動かしたいのでpyinstallerでexe化して配布を行う。
・python実行は動きます。
・自身のPCでexe化したファイルを実行するとエラーが吐き出されずに途中で止まってしまいます。（作成したexeファイルが消えます…）
・他のPC（python環境がない）でexeファイルを実行すると動きます
一応他のPCで動くので実現したい事は出来てるのですが、自身のPCでテストが出来ないため問題解決にお手を貸して頂けますか？
環境
Windows10
python 3.12.0
pyinstaller 6.6.0
実際のコード
import os
import send2trash
from tkinter import messagebox

def move_files_to_trash(folders, excluded_extensions):
    try:
        confirmation = messagebox.askokcancel("実行前確認", "[ダウンロード・ピクチャ・ドキュメント・ビデオ・ミュージック]\nの中身をゴミ箱に移動します")
        if confirmation:
            for folder in folders:
                files = os.listdir(folder)
                for file in files:
                    if not file.endswith(excluded_extensions):
                        file_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
                        send2trash.send2trash(file_path)
                        print(file + "をゴミ箱に移動しました")
            messagebox.showinfo("お知らせ", "ゴミ箱に移動しました")                
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("お知らせ", "キャンセルしました")
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("エラー", "処理中にエラーが発生しました:\n" + str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # フォルダのパス
    download_dir = os.path.expanduser('~\\Downloads')
    pictures_dir = os.path.expanduser('~\\Pictures')
    documents_dir = os.path.expanduser('~\\Documents')
    video_dir = os.path.expanduser('~\\Videos')
    music_dir = os.path.expanduser('~\\Music')

    # 各フォルダをリストに格納
    folders_to_process = [download_dir, pictures_dir, documents_dir, video_dir, music_dir]
    # 削除しない拡張子のリスト
    excluded_extensions = ('.ini', '.exe', '.bat')
    
    move_files_to_trash(folders_to_process, excluded_extensions)


files = os.listdir(folder) の部分はファイル以外(サブフォルダーなど) も含まれるのでは？その可能性はないですか？

はい、この部分はファイル以外（フォルダ内全てを取得したい）も含まれます。
間違っていますかね…？

サブフォルダー(サブディレクトリー)を移す場合, その中に入ってる *.ini, *.exe, *.bat は除外されることなく移動なのは仕様ですか？

サブフォルダー内に入っている次の拡張子ファイル（.ini, *.exe, *.bat）に関しては移動する仕様でOKです。

作成した exe が消えてしまうのであれば、マルウェアとして検知されていませんか？こちら「https://qiita.com/tru-y/items/cb3cebe9612d367dccb2」に、pyinstaller で exe を生成した場合に、マルウェアとして検知されることがあると記載があります。

@ABC ディレクトリ構造が記されていないので推測でしかないけど, 実行中に自分自身を移動させようとした可能性があるのでは？ (サブディレクトリーに入っていたなどで)

ありがとうございます。
マルウェアとして検知されているようです…
